# currency not updating when changing currency

Tags: currency

I don't understand why currency is not working properly.

I have kept base currency as INR and When choosing the USD or Euro Or GBP, its still shows the base Indian rate and uses the currency symbol of other currencies.

Please check attached files.

[image]
[image]

Comment: have you find the solution for this? otherwise i will help you

Answer (score 0):

This issue is because two reasons.

1. Re-index all data after change currency.
2. Clear all cache and refresh.

**I hope this will help you.**

Comment: tried few more times but its not working still.

Comment: some people asked me to type but i do not know where to type this text {{block type="catalog/product_new" template="catalog/product/new.phtml" cache_lifetime="1"}}